# How to manage tests which require an API key

Tags: go

I have some hermetic tests, and those work fine. Code in `foo.go` gets tested in `foo_test.go`.

But also I have some tests which need an API key, and I want to keep these tests separate from the hermetic tests, since we don't run them in CI.

How can I effectively segregate and these tests in a way that works well with the Go tools and ecosystem?

Comment: Provide the key via an environment variabel and skip the test is unset or collect these test in a file protected via some build tag. No need for "directory strucutre" here.

Comment: I think I prematurely voted to close. I'm sorry for that. The original wording I (and apparently others) interpreted as too broad.  But I don't think it really needs to be taken that way. I've made a small edit to the question to help focus it, and voted to re-open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to skip tests. Most of them leverage [testing.T.Skip(Now)](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T.SkipNow). Following are a few common use-cases for SkipNow. However, since this is just like any old function call you can get as creative as you want.

## Using an environment variable

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func TestAlways(t *testing.T) {
}

func TestSometimes(t *testing.T) {
    key := os.Getenv("FOO_API_KEY")
    if key == "" {
        t.Skip("FOO_API_KEY is empty")
    }
}
```

Run one of:

```bash
go test -v
FOO_API_KEY=bar go test -v
```

## Using the built-in `short` flag

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestAlways(t *testing.T) {
    // ...
}

func TestSometimes(t *testing.T) {
    if testing.Short() {
        t.Skip("-short is set")
    }

    // ...
}
```

Run one of:

```
go test -v -short
go test -v
```

## Using a custom flag

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "testing"
)

var withFoo = false // or true to run test by default

func init() {
    flag.BoolVar(&withFoo, "with-foo", withFoo, "Include foo tests")
}

func TestAlways(t *testing.T) {
    // ...
}

func TestSometimes(t *testing.T) {
    if !withFoo {
        t.Skip("-with-foo is not set")
    }

    // ...
}
```

Run one of:

```
go test -v
go test -v -with-foo
```

## Using [build constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/go/build#hdr-Build_Constraints)

```
// main_test.go
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestAlways(t *testing.T) {
    // ...
}
```

```
// foo_test.go
//go:build foo
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestSometimes(t *testing.T) {
    // ...
}
```

Run one of:

```
go test -v
go test -v -tags=foo
```

Note that with build tags the output will not indicate that tests have been skipped. The tagged .go files simply become invisible to the compiler unless the build tag is included on the command line (or in GOFLAGS).